# Tengo un problema extraño! con [display flex y grid]

Tags: html, css, css3, diseño

la verdad es la primera vez que me pasa. Pero el problema esta cuando uso display flex o grid se desforma el contenido.

Esto es sin el `display: grid;`
[image: Esto es sin el display grid]

Así queda cuando uso `display: grid;`
[image: Así queda cuando uso display grid]

El div contenedor tiene esta clase

```
.post-container {
    background-color: #fff1;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 35px 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

y lo que serían los iconos tiene otro div que tiene un `position:sticky` y la clase que contiene la información a mostrar no tiene ningún valor, esta solo para envolver el contenido.

Alguien sabe por que es? ya probé de todo!

Pero creo que la única solución es usarlo así, pero igual forma quisiera saber si existe otra forma o a que se debe el error.

```
.post-container {
    background-color: #fff1;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 35px calc(100% - 5%);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

desde ya Muchas Gracias!